# Calculate the norm of $f$ in $\mathbb{C}[a,b]$

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

Let $X=\mathbb{C}[a,b]$ with the norm $\Vert x\Vert=\max_{a\le t\le b}|x(t)|$,

If we have $t_1,\cdots, t_n\in [a,b]$ and $\lambda_1,\cdots, \lambda_n\in \mathbb{C}$. If and let $f(x)=\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_i\cdot x(t_i), ~\forall ~x\in \mathbb{C}[a,b]$.

How can I calculate the  norm of $f$ ?

By $|f(x)|=\Vert\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_i\cdot x(t_i)\Vert\le \sum_{i=1}^n\Vert \lambda_i\Vert\cdot \Vert x\Vert$, we get $f$ is bounded and $\Vert f\Vert\le \sum_{i=1}^n\Vert \lambda_i\Vert$

But how can I calculate $\Vert f\Vert$?

If $\lambda_1,\cdots, \lambda_n\in \mathbb{R}$, we let $x(t_i)=1$ if $\lambda_i\ge 0$ and $x(t_i)=-1$ if $\lambda_i\le 0$.

If connect these point with lines to get the function $x(t)$, we have $| f(x)|=\sum_{i=1}^n\Vert \lambda_i\Vert$.

So we get $\Vert f\Vert=\sum_{i=1}^n\Vert \lambda_i\Vert $.

But here $\lambda_i\in \mathbb{C}$, how can I calculate $\Vert f\Vert$?

Thanks!

Comment: With the same idea set $x(t_i)=0$ if $\lambda_i=0$ and $x(t_i)=\overline{\lambda_i}/|\lambda_i|$ if $\lambda_i \not=0$ (and replace $\|\lambda_i\|$ by $|\lambda_i|$).